# Pyspotify - periodic "the track cannot be played error"

Tags: python

I have a problem with pyspotify. I'm trying to search for an artist name, get a list of their top tracks and then play one of them. This is my code segment:

```
    search_string = "artist:"+artist_to_find
    result = session.search(search_string)
            result.load()
    print result.track_total
    browser = result.artists[0].browse()
    browser.load()
    print browser.tophit_tracks
    for track in browser.tophit_tracks:
    print track.name, track
            toptracks = browser.tophit_tracks
    print "error check"
    if toptracks!=-1:
        print "------------------"
        tracktoplay=choice(toptracks)
        rand = randint(0,10)
        print "random track number = %s" %rand
        tracktoplay = browser.tophit_tracks[rand]
        print tracktoplay.link
        print tracktoplay.name
        print "------------------"
        session.player.load(tracktoplay)
        session.player.play()
```

I frequently call this code without the previous track finishing. Perodically (every few tracks) I get the following error:

```
random track number = 7
spotify:track:6vQN2a9QSgWcm74KEZYfDL
Take A Chance On Me
------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../jj.py", line 146, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "../jj.py", line 116, in run
    conversation.handleForever()
  File "/home/mh/Projects/jjo/client/conversation.py", line 44, in handleForever
    listen(self)
  File "/home/mh/Projects/jjo/client/new_play.py", line 110, in listen
    play(self,response)
  File "/home/mh/Projects/jjo/client/new_play.py", line 194, in play
    session.player.load(tracktoplay)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spotify/player.py", line 45, in load
    self._session._sp_session, track._sp_track))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spotify/error.py", line 30, in maybe_raise
    raise LibError(error_type)
spotify.error.LibError: The track cannot be played
```

Can anyone advise on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I've found that I'm getting the error SP_ERROR_TRACK_NOT_PLAYABLE from the libspotify "sp_session_player_play" function. I've hacked the code (player.py in the spotify library to report unloaded instead of an error) to make my code re-try if it fails but can anyone tell me why a track could be deemed not playable? When I take the link and play it in my brower, the link is valid and the track plays without a problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experiece on pyspotify, but I was looking at it out of curiosity.

If I was you I would check the [PlayerState](https://pyspotify.mopidy.com/en/latest/api/player/#spotify.player.PlayerState) is LOADED before I call play()

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried adding a check for the track being loaded but it hasn't helped. 
`while True:
 if session.player.state=='loaded':
  break`